# presentation selection change

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins

We can detect when a slide get selected by SlideSelectionChanged.

Do we have the same event for presentation selection change?

for example, I have 3 presentations on the screen. How can we know when a presentation get selected?

Note: I am using PowerPoint 2013, VS Ultimate 2013

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [Application level events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229334(v=office.15).aspx) for PowerPoint 2013. I'm guessing that the [WindowActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743995(v=office.15).aspx) event might be the one you need.